# Enabling TextBox with trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger

I want a Textbox to be disabled, except the user hovers with the mouse over it. But this does not seam to work, the Textbox is still not editable if I hover over it. (Yes I know that this is unusual.)
What I tried is:

```
<Border>
    <TextBox Text="Hover to edit me!" IsEnabled="False" >
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Border}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <!-- this does not work either -->
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                         <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <!-- neither did this -->
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
</Border>
```

I wonder if it is possible at all using a trigger?

Comment: Might be missing the point but why don't you bind to IsMouseOver directly?

Comment: Good question! I tried that too, but it also did not work, I i checked if I could bind it to an outer element, Border in this case, also without luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the [Dependency Property Value Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence) in WPF.

You need to set the `IsEnabled` property to `false` in the `Style`, so the trigger can override the value.

The local value has always a higher priority, so setting `IsEnabled="False"` directly in the text box will override any style or style trigger value.

Here is a working example:

```
  <Border>
    <TextBox Text="Text">
      <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
          <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
          <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger
                Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Border}}"
                Value="True">
              <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
      </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
  </Border>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not know about the value precedence. First time I stumbled across. That does in deed work.